# angular-file-uploader Additional parameters

Tags: angular, upload

How can I add additional arguments to the web api using [angular-file-uploader](https://github.com/kzrfaisal/angular-file-uploader/blob/master/README.md)?

The upload end point is to post to a .net core web api, it is working fine and I can also send the headers as well, but I need to supply additional arguments as well. I have seen some examples sending it through formData, but I am not able to retrieve the data from my API.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Hello there, old story, Are you having the same problem? will check on Tuesday when I'm back to work and let you know.